# How setup intellisense for webpack bundle in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, webpack

I am using **webpack** to compile Typescript into **Javascript** and then bundle it into single **Javascript** file which i then use in all of my asp.net core views. I the bundled code executes without problem. But I cannot get any intellisense support on anything inside bundle.

Bundle is included in _Layout.cshtml inside script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get any intellisense because the bundle is already combine and uglify and even mangle so Visual Studio cant provide any intellisense for you.

If you want to use any intellisense when working with webpack I'm suggest you use visual studio code it has reach intellisense system built in.